Deciding whether a linear combination of logarithm of primes is positive
Suppose that $p_i$ are (finitely many, mutually distinct) prime numbers and $a_i$ non-zero integers. It can be shown that $S = \sum a_i \cdot \log(p_i) \neq 0$ (since $\log(p_i)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, see e.g. here).
Now, I am wondering whether we can efficiently decide whether $S$ is positive or negative.
From Baker's theorem, we know that if such a sum is non-zero, there exists an (effectively computable) value $h$ such that $|S| > h$, which gives decidability by approximating the logarithms sufficiently, but not much more ($h$ is, as far as I can tell, really small in general).
Baker's theorem however is quite a powerful tool, so I am wondering whether the restriction to integers and primes allows for something simpler (in terms of computational complexity).

There is a naive algorithm with running time at most $O((\sum a_i)^2 n^2)$ where $n = \max_i \lg p_i$.  Consequently, this can be computed efficiently (in polynomial time) if the $a_i$'s are small integers or if they are represented in unary.
The algorithm is to simply check whether
$$\prod_{a_i>0} p_i^{a_i} > \prod_{a_i<0} p_i^{-a_i}$$
by computing both sides as integers.  The left-hand side is a product over all $i$ such that $a_i$ is positive, etc.  Each side can be expressed using at most $n \sum a_i$ bits, from which we obtain the running time bound listed above.
If the $a_i$'s are provided in binary, the running time is exponential (in the length of the input).  This still is better than nothing.
I don't know whether there is any better algorithm.

How silly of me! The proof that $\log(p_i)$ is linearly independent exactly uses the fact that $\prod_{a_i > 0} p_i^{a_i} \neq \prod_{a_i < 0} p_i^{-a_i}$ (uniqueness of the prime decomposition). So its been staring at me all along. At first glance, exponential should be fine. In my context, I actually want to see if $\sum a_i \log r_i > 0$ for rational $r_i$, so I have to compute their prime factors anyway.

The problem is of course the situation where the sum is very close to zero. If you have n logarithms and integers up to 10^k, then you have about 10^(nk) different possible
Sums up to about n x 10^k. The distance between two sums is about n / 10^(nk - k). To distinguish two sums from 0 you need about nk - k digits precision. You should be able to do the calculation with enouggh precision in time polynomial in nk, and the problem size is also about nk. So checking if a sum is less than or greater than zero should take polynomial time.
There might be errors in the calculation, and I have no idea how bad the worst case could be, but in general polynomial time should be enough.
In the end, you calculate the logarithm of the quotient of two huge integers. You could just calculate both of these huge integers and check which one is larger. The number of digits could be huge.
